# Sqoop export from Parquet to MySQL error

Tags: sqoop, parquet

My Sqoop version is  1.4.6-cdh5.7.0.
My Sqoop command is:

```
sqoop export --table customerservicerep --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/3febbraio \
--username training --password training --update-mode allowinsert \
--export-dir /3febbraio/sqoop_parquet/customerservicerep --verbose
```

The error I get is:

```
2018-02-04 02:16:04,098 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 1 in block 0 in file hdfs://localhost:8020/3febbraio/sqoop_parquet/customerservicerep/64e8ebb2-46fa-41c4-aef2-dac336a27c82.parquet
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:241)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:227)
    at org.kitesdk.data.spi.filesystem.AbstractCombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(AbstractCombineFileRecordReader.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
    at org.kitesdk.data.spi.AbstractKeyRecordReaderWrapper.nextKeyValue(AbstractKeyRecordReaderWrapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: customerservicerep cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord
    at parquet.avro.AvroIndexedRecordConverter.start(AvroIndexedRecordConverter.java:185)
    at parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.read(RecordReaderImplementation.java:391)
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:216)
    ... 16 more
```

For some reason Sqoop is trying to treat the Parquet file as an Avro file. How can I fix it?

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot export the parquet files using sqoop, Have you ever exported the parquet files to any RDBMS before?

Comment: @rob no, I have never export parquet files before

Comment: If I'm in your shoes, I would create a CSV file out of the table I want to export or to an external table and do the sqoop export job using that file. Let me know if you are interested in the approach I can provide the code snip.

Comment: @rob thank you, I was just doing some exercises for a certification and I was trying to import and export all possible formats.

Comment: You can convert the parquet to the hive default delimited text file (\001) and export this directory OR you can use the option of exporting hive table of sqoop